# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot' matplotlib error

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

I'm trying to use methods on my axis, although it displays the error

'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

[Matplotlib error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvPBr.png)

Comment: Usually better to show your work, but assuming you did something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)` then you need to index `ax` to use the methods: `ax[0].plot()`, `ax[1].imshow()`.  `ax` is an ndarray of pointers to your axes.

Comment: Methods only work for the class of object for which they are defined.  If you get an error like this, either you have read the wrong documentation, or the object in question isn't the class that you think it is.  Check the `type` of the object, and check the relevant docs.

Comment: The problem in the code in the image is that `axis` is 2D in this case and it is used as if it were 1D. For example: `axis[0][2].plot(x, y)` would use the third `axis`. `axis[2]` is a subarray containing the third row of axes (`axis[2]` is of type 'numpy.ndarray').